# Silently authenticate to a URL via basic auth in C#

Tags: c#

I need to build a C# application which accepts a specific URL as input and loads the webpage (which is all text) into a string.  The difficulty is that this URL requires basic authentication in order to load the page.  I need to hard-code the credentials into the app; I can't have the user enter it themselves.  I don't believe it is possible to pass the username & p/w in as part of the URL.  Is there a way to handle this silently with C#?

Here is how, in very basic terms, I would load the page if authentication wasn't required:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 0)
        return;

    WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
    string output = webclient.DownloadString(args[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: What kind of authentication? If its general http auth, you could always enable URL authentication and pass your username/password into the URL. Like: http://username:password@www.yourWebSite.com

Comment: what technology, WCF, ASP.NET, Desktop ???

Comment: - I believe it's asking for basic authentication, however username:password@[URL] did not work.

- I am writing the app in .NET.  The web server is McAfee ePolicy Orchestrator (which I believe is Apache/Tomcat)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is just a header in your request to the webserver. Add the `Authorization` header along with the correct values and you are good.

The following is an example of that header:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

`Basic` is required because you want to use the basic authentication
`QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==` is the Base64 representation of *username:password*, in this case `Aladdin:open sesame`

When using the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class, you don't have to write that header yourself, you can use the [`Credentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property before the call to `DownloadString`:

```
webclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
```

Comment: Thanks - Do you happen to have a code sample that shows where that goes?

Comment: I updated my question with some sample code showing basically what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @MikeBruno: Updated answer, please check.